# Kenshi UI question; clicking the 'Block' button doesn't always switch behavior

Tags: kenshi

I often need to change the behavior of more than one character in my Kenshi game. For example, I might need to turn Block, Hold or Passive off of everyone in a squad. If I have selected more than one character at a time, clicking on those buttons doesn't consistently change them all to that behavior. I end up having to check/select every character in my squad to confirm and/or change their setting, which is tedious.

Is there any way to consistently change the behavior flags for more than one character at a time? Note that I am currently playing a .99 version of the game, so it is possible this is a fixed bug in more current versions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember the hot keys, but what you should do is to create multiple squads, then put people with a certain desired behavior in a certain squad. So you can have for example:

- One melee squad for fighting everything & chase down runners if desired.
- One ranged squad which only shoots what you tell them to shoot. This is a must, since it is the key to surviving friendly fire.
- One civilian/injured squad not fighting at all.

Comment: I do break my people in multiple squads, but I normally break my squads up by location; for example one at Squin, one at my base, and one out exploring and looking for fights. I normally put my entire combat group into one squad; this makes it is much easier to trade stuff and make them all go to a location. I am trying to avoid the workaround of breaking them into separate 'mele' and 'crossbowmen' squads, which may be required to fix the problems with the UI not working as expected when selecting multiple chars and clicking the 'hold' or 'ranged' buttons.

Comment: @MarkRipley If you want to do exploring and searching for ruins, note that the foes you meet when going northwest, south or southeast can be very nasty. The key to surviving is to have 20+ high-level members and utilize crossbows as much as possible. The same goes when assaulting a hostile city, if you are involved in some of the big faction quests. Unfortunately, crossbows also need a whole lot of manual attention or you'll wipe out your own squad quickly. I don't think there's a way around micro-managing the archers and press pause a whole lot during combat.

Comment: Yep, I noticed the need for micromanagement when using crossbows. But friendly fire damage also increases shooter precision, which keeps my chars from one-shot killing my chars when using the much more powerful turrets, and any non-lethal damage I take is a good thing, since it increases toughness. I usually key-bind 'n' to 'next char in squad', then select the first char in the squad, and then right-click, 'n', right-click, 'n', and repeat along a line at right angle to enemies while the game is paused, and then when I un-pause my chars make a nice straight line and don't shoot each other.

Answer (score 0):

This may be something you already are aware of, but I figured I would share just in case... when you select a group and change a behavior such as blocking and the group has some people who were already blocking, in my experience you have to toggle the button a few times to "get everyone on the same page". This is more apparent with the sneaking skill.

Comment: Yes, I had noticed that behavior. I usually do toggle my squad multiple times in the way you describe because this is more reliable than just toggling a squad's behavior (button) once, but it doesn't always assure that everyone is doing what I want them to do. The only way I have found to 'get everyone on the same page' is to pause, multiple toggle a behavior button with everyone selected, and then finally manually check the settings on each selected squad member. This is such a fiddly procedure that it drove me to ask this question.